# How to create table from json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js

**JSON PART  :**

```
{
    "1": {"JAN": {"ID": "1","Name": "Jim"}},
    "2": {"FEB": {"ID": "2","Name": "Jack" } },
    "Idname" : "2",
    "Date" : "01/28/2014",
    "State" : "1"
}
```

I need the above json to create a table in the following format.

**HTML PART :**

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>{{JAN}}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>                                
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ID}}</td>
        <td>{{Name}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I need both header and body of table from json. Also only one part of the whole json will be shown as table, rest will be shown as normal fields.

Comment: Have you tried using JSON.parse()? It will give you requried data. and then you can but that into thead or tbody

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718215/create-table-from-json-object-in-javascript

Comment: I think you must see to handlebars.js, and use JSON.parse to parse data from server

Comment: can you explain in detail about  JSON.parse because I didn't understand about it..

Comment: The `"1": {"JAN":` is the `"1"` going to remain constant or will it change ?

Comment: 1 will be same for Jan..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JSON.parse to parse data from the server.

```
 s1 =  // required data store it here
 name: '1',
 data: JSON.parse("[" + s1 + "]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
for (var i in json) {
    if (typeof (json[i]) == "object") {
        var month = json[i];
        var headd='';
        var bodyy='';
        for (var j in month) {
            headd='<th>'+j+'</th>';
            var tbody = month[j];
            bodyy='<tr><td>'+ tbody.ID + '</td><td>' + tbody.Name+'</td><tr>';

        }
        $("#head_t").append(headd)
        $("#body_t").append(bodyy)
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4xXpV/)

Comment: i updated the json part..Kindly let me know the solution for it..check the new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22130859/creating-table-using-json-data